# Автопрокрутка jTextArea в Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, gui, netbeans

Есть `jTextArea`, созданная в визуальном редакторе Netbeans IDE. Когда в ней появляется большое количество текста, появляется скролл.

Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении текста `jTextArea` сама прокручивалась вниз?

Comment: разве jtextarea автоматически не прокручивает вниз что при ручном вводе текста, что при вставке текста? либо я не понял вопрос.

Comment: Нет, не прокручивает. Ну у меня текст увеличивается постепенно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете либо сами ставить каретку в конец текста:

```
textArea.append("Тут текст");
textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
```

Либо чтобы это было всегда автоматически:

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

<sub>[Источник0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627028/how-to-set-auto-scrolling-of-jtextarea-in-java-gui) и [Источник1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365847/how-to-auto-scroll-down-jtextarea-after-append).</sub>